# How to make fullcalendar time row selectable in AgendaWeek / AgendaDay view?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

[image]

Using fullcalendar plugin, we can select the time range by drugging inside of calendar body. I would like to select time range on its time row as marked in above picture. Is there any fullcalendar way to do this? I need help about this.

Comment: No there is no way to do it. It wouldn't make sense to do so... because it would only select a time, not a date, therefore you wouldn't know what exact place the user was trying to select. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi @ADyson , thanks for your valuable comment. I am working on fullcalendar select option, which allows to select time / date range from calendar. When there are multiples bookings in the same day in week view / day view it is very hard to select cell from calendar. Which is why I thought it would be good if I can let user select time range from time row.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately the UI doesn't support that directly. I suggest the approach should be to allow the user to select the time/date of the first booking, and then pop up a modal box with a form which allows them to choose whether the event will repeat at the same time on subsequent days (just like you can in Outlook, or Google Calendar, for example). Unfortunately though, because you said you use an old version of fullCalendar you will not be able to take advantage of the Recurring Events functionality now built into the engine, which makes it easy to specify recurrence in the event data.

Comment: If you upgrade to fullCalendar 4 or above, you can use the recurring events functionality, plus the RRule plugin for more complex recurrence. If not, then you would simply have to create the repeating events as separate event objects yourself.

Comment: @ADyson , Thank you. It makes sense.